# Rapsberry Pi Wifi not working with wpa_passphrase

Tags: raspbian

after getting my edimax wifi stick to work on my raspberri pi I have one little problem left.

I my config file I'm using my plain wifi key, which I don't like to have there
e.g

```
network={
ssid="Foobar"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="myplainKey"
}
```

If I try to insert my passphrased key e.g

```
network={
ssid="Foobar"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="28392u92skjwhdjkhewj23393kjisdxk"
}
```

I'm getting this ugly guy here

```
raspberry pi wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
```

What config needs to be done to use passphrase in my supplicant.conf file?

Thank you

Comment: Ok, did you test it by passing the correct config file to wpa_supplicant?

Comment: Yes i changed it in same File, so that seems to be correct

Comment: Can you try starting wpa_supplicant with `-d` (debugging) and post the output? If that doesn't show much, try with `-dd` too